# Calculate the page number on which item is present using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, pagination

I have 20 items in total, per page 5 items

How to calculate the page number if know `id` of item in general using javascript.

Possible formula or way to calculate the page number by id value

```
example:

let itemsTotal = 20;
let perPage = 5;
let itemId=25;
let pageForThisProduct = Math.ceil(itemId/itemsTotal);
```

Comment: That depends entirely on how the items are ordered in the pages, and in the case that they are ordered by a numeric property, if there are any gaps in the sequence (i. e. in your example you should have 20 items, but you're trying to find the item with id 25, so it's clear that the ids are not 1-20 or 0-19). However, you can always know the total number of items, how many items per page there are, and you can iterate through the items to find at which index in the sequence a given item is. That should be enough to tell in which page it appears.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper thanks, let say if index 6 for itemId, then the formula should be like (index/itemsperpage)+remainder?

Comment: Well, no. If you have 5 items per page, and the item you want to find is the sixth item, then it's in the second page. But so would be the seventh item. And the remainder is not 1 in both cases.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper is there way to calculate this, yes i knw its second page, how to get 2, if index 15, i would i say 3 , formula to calculate that

Answer (score 0):

You're close. You don't divide the current item in the list by the number of items - you divide the current item by the number of items allowed per page (or limit).

```js
function getPageNum(item, limit = 5) {
  return Math.ceil(item / limit);
}

console.log(`Item 1 is on page ${getPageNum(1)}`);
console.log(`Item 5 is on page ${getPageNum(5)}`);
console.log(`Item 7 is on page ${getPageNum(7)}`);
console.log(`Item 10 is on page ${getPageNum(10)}`);
console.log(`Item 13 is on page ${getPageNum(13)}`);
console.log(`Item 15 is on page ${getPageNum(15)}`);
console.log(`Item 16 is on page ${getPageNum(16)}`);
console.log(`Item 20 is on page ${getPageNum(20)}`);
console.log(`Item 21 is on page ${getPageNum(21)}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the page number based on ID:

```
let itemsTotal = 20;
let perPage = 5;
let itemId = 25;
let pageForThisProduct = Math.ceil(itemId / perPage);
```

The variable pageForThisProduct will store the page number and you can display based on your functionality.